# Logging contents of S3 file to postgres table with Node.js and AWS Lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm writing an [AWS Lambda](http://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) execution script in node.js that responds to an S3 put event (log files), reads the file and inserts into a Postgres table via the COPY command. It appears that everything except writing to the database (`logToPostgres` in the script below) is working as expected.

Some notes:

- I've removed the part where it checks to verify that it's an S3 put event, and other error handling code since it's not relevant here.
- The database user has `INSERT` permissions on the table and `ALL` on the database and can access from any IP (all verified).
- `secrets.js` is a module in the same directory that exports the database credentials
- I can write to the database fine when running the script locally.
- I'm not hitting any of AWS Lambda's limits — the file downloaded from S3 is 521 bytes and the timeout is set to max 60 seconds (it runs in under 300ms when testing and writing to the same DB).

There are no errors in cloud watch and by adding logging at every step, I was able to narrow it down to the `stream.pipe(query)...` part of the code. For some reason, this part is not being executed by AWS Lambda, whereas it runs fine locally. It is not emitting the `'finished'` and `'end'` events, so my guess is that it remains unexecuted.

Any thoughts on where the problem might be?

```
var async = require('async');
var fs = require('fs');
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new aws.S3();
var pg = require('pg');
var pgCopy = require('pg-copy-streams').from;
var secrets = require('./secrets.js');

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    var bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    var key = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;

    async.waterfall(
        [
            function downloadWebhook(next) {
                s3.getObject({Bucket: bucket, Key: key}, next);
            },
            function saveToDisk(response, next) {
                var file = fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/foo_' + Date.now());
                file.write(response.Body);
                file.close();
                next(null, file.path);
            },
            function createStdinStream(path, next) {
                next(null, fs.createReadStream(path));
            },
            function logToPostgres(stream, next) {
                var client = new pg.Client('pg://' + secrets.user + ':' +
                    secrets.password + '@' + secrets.host + ':' +
                    secrets.port + '/' + secrets.database);
                client.connect(function (error) {
                    if (error) console.error(error);
                    var query = client.query(pgCopy('COPY my_table FROM STDIN'));
                    stream.pipe(query)
                        .on('finish', function () {
                            client.end();
                            next(null, null);
                        });
                });
            }
        ],
        function (error) {
            if (error) console.error(error);
            context.done();
        }
    });
};
```

---

#### Update:

It turns out that writable streams now emit the `'finish'` event, so changing it to `'finish'` and including the suggestion from the answer makes it run without errors. However there still isn't a row in the database after the lambda has run. I suspect that the transaction is being rolled back but cannot pinpoint why or where. I even tried explicitly beginning and committing a transaction but no dice.

Comment: Check [Lambda Limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html) to make sure that you're not reaching those and also add a `query.on('error', function(error) {...});` [error handler](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Query#error--object-error) to your `logToPostgres` method as it is probably crashing there.

Comment: @TristanFoureur I'm not hitting any of those limits. The file size is 520 bytes and on local machine, everything finishes in under 200ms (lambda time out is set to 60s on my function). I did have `on('error'... )` for `query` following the piping but that event either isn't fired (because nothing executed) or there were no errors. Note that AWS lambda finishes running cleanly with no reported errors. There just isn't anything in the database table.

Comment: @TristanFoureur Please also see my response to William Gaul's suggestion below.

Answer (score 0):

`context.done()` halts your Lambda function's execution immediately. Thus when you call `next(null, null)`, the waterfall completes and because your Postgres query is asynchronous, it won't get run to completion.

Try instead:

```
stream.pipe(query)
    .on('end', function() {
        client.end();
        next(null, null);
    })
    .on('error', context.fail);
```

Note how here, we only resolve the waterfall once the stream has ended.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. It now appears that the stream just won't terminate, so the `on('end'...)` part is never reached. The function ends up being killed due to the timeout. The file size is 521 bytes. What's more confusing is that I don't see a connection in postgres using `select * from pg_stat_activity;` during the lambda execution. The same code when run locally shows the connection for the duration of execution (I also tested locally and on AWS by commenting out the `client.end()` part so the connection is still alive).

Comment: Hmm even with the max timeout of 60 seconds? Have you configured your DB to listen for connections over TCP/IP?

Comment: Yup, the DB listens to connections over TCP/IP and this user is authorized to connect from any IP. When I tested locally, the DB was still remote (credentials, table, invocation, all being the same) and it worked. And yeah, my lambda uses max timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what was wrong with your solution. Here is my tested and more compact solution. Please let me know if this works!

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new aws.S3();
var S3S = require('s3-streams');
var pg = require('pg');
var pgCopy = require('pg-copy-streams').from;
var secrets = require('./secrets.js');

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    var bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    var key = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;

    var stream = S3S.ReadStream(s3, {Bucket: bucket, Key: key});
    pg.connect(secrets.connector, function(err, client) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        var query = client.query(pgCopy(
            "COPY event_log(user_id, event, ...) FROM STDIN CSV"
        ));
        stream.pipe(query)
            .on('end', function () {
                client.end();
                context.done();
            })
            .on('error', function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    });
};
```

Comment: Btw you should use end instead of finish: http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_events_finish_and_end